# Update data on Json file using php

Tags: php, html, json, forms, updating

i have this code to create a json file on server and save form data to that jason file.

the problem is every time i hit submit button, form data append to existing data on json file.

I would like to update it not create more copy line.

here is the code, you can check it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Photo"]["tmp_name"],"images/".$_POST['Photo']);

    $filters=array(
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "Photo",
        "MobilePhone",
        "MobilePhoneProvider",
        "HomePhone",
        "HomePhoneProvider",
        "WorkPhone",
        "WorkPhoneProvider"
    );

    $final=array();

    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        $final[$filter]=$_POST[$filter]?$_POST[$filter]:"";
    }

    $final["PhoneNumber"]=array(
        array(
            "MobilePhone"=>$final["MobilePhone"],
            "Provider"=>$final["MobilePhoneProvider"],
        ),
        array(
            "HomePhone"=>$final["HomePhone"],
            "Provider"=>$final["HomePhoneProvider"],
        ),
        array(
            "WorkPhone"=>$final["WorkPhone"],
            "Provider"=>$final["WorkPhoneProvider"],
        )
    );

    $unsets=array(
        "MobilePhone",
        "MobilePhoneProvider",
        "HomePhone",
        "HomePhoneProvider",
        "WorkPhone",
        "WorkPhoneProvider"
    );

    foreach ($unsets as $unset) {
        unset($final[$unset]);
    }



$json = json_encode( $final );
$file = 'entries.json';
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);

    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br>
            Photo: <input type="file" name="Photo"><br>
            Mobile Phone: <input type="tel" name="MobilePhone"><br>
            Mobile Phone Provider: <input type="text" name="MobilePhoneProvider"><br>
            Home Phone: <input type="tel" name="HomePhone"><br>
            Home Phone Provider: <input type="text" name="HomePhoneProvider"><br>
            Work Phone: <input type="tel" name="WorkPhone"><br>
            Work Phone Provider: <input type="text" name="WorkPhoneProvider"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing `file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);` to `file_put_contents( $file, $json);` as per the [docs for `FILE_APPEND` flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) -> `If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.`

Comment: Yes, it's really quick solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$file = 'entries.json';
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
if(!(is_array($data) AND !empty($data))) {
    $data = array();
}
$data[] = $final;
$data = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: but I don't understand why You're not using DB for this operations?
at least You can use sqlite to properly store datas.

Comment: Thanks man, it's cool. but sorry i can't vote up your answer because i have just 11 reputation. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing as an json, you can persist php array itself in a file and retrieve easily.
some thing like this.

```
file_put_contents('entries.php', '<?php $final = ' . var_export($final, true) . ';');
```

to retrieve array simply include that 'entries.php' file wherever you want.

```
include_once('entries.php');
```

Comment: Sounds good man thanks, yes it's easy to use.
sorry i can't vote up your answer because i have just 11 reputation. thanks again.